# Cauchy sequence where the set of outputs is finite

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

If $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and $S = \{a_n |n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is finite, then $\{a_n\}$ is constant from some point on.

The statement makes sense, but I'm not quite sure how to start. I feel like maybe contradiction, saying if it wasn't constant from some point on, $S$ couldn't be finite.

What I have so far:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence, so for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $n^{*}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $| a_m -a_n| < \epsilon$ for all $m \geq n^*$  and all $n \geq n^*$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If S has only one member the sequence is already constant. Otherwise:

Let $d$ be the minimum of $|a_n-a_m|$ over all pairs $n,m$ with $a_n \neq a_m$ [This exists and is positive since $S$ is finite.] Now apply Cauchy to some $\epsilon < d.$

Added: About applying Cauchy: Fix $0< \epsilon <d.$ Then by Cauchy there is $n_0$ such that for $n,m \ge n_0$ we have $|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon <d.$ By the way $d$ was defined, we cannot have[with $n,m \ge n_0$] $a_n \neq a_m,$ else $|a_n-a_m| \ge d>\epsilon.$

Comment: I guess I'm still confused as to how to apply the Cauchy definition to $\epsilon < d$.

Comment: @lia.riley I have tried for an explanation in the part called "Added."

Answer (score 1):

Consider $d:=\min\{|a_n - a_m|\mid \forall n,m\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Since $S$ is finite, the sequence $\{a_n\}$ only takes on finitely many different values, and so this minimum exists. Then let $\epsilon= \frac{d}{2}$ and use the definition of a Cauchy sequence together with the fact that $S$ is finite.

**Edit:** I should have added that the argument above holds if the sequence is not constant. If the sequence is constant, then there is nothing to prove.

Comment: Great answer, I was going to suggest the same thing.  Two things:  the $\frac{1}{2}$ factor in the definition of $\varepsilon$ isn't necessary, and at some point a contradiction will be helpful.

Comment: @Aweygan I agree that using contradiction can be useful at the end. I edited my answer. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: If the sequence is constant, then $d=0$. Since we don't want $\epsilon = 0$, we need to be consider this case separately. Thanks to coffeemath for pointing this out in his answer.

Comment: But how does this imply the sequence is constant from some point on?

Comment: Let $\epsilon = \frac{d}{2}$. By definition of the Cauchy sequence, there is a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m,n \geq N$ we have that $|a_m - a_n|<\epsilon$. But if $a_m$ and $a_n$ differ _less_ than the minimal distance between different values, then all the $a_n$ have to be constant for $n \geq N$.